# Python request sessions is not working for put/post in next call

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Hi i am trying to access one rest api with can be accessed only after login. I was using below code but getting 401, access denied. I am sure if same cookies will be applied to next put call, it will not give access denied. but python session is not using the same cookies.. instead adding new cookies..thanks..

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    logging.info("Trying to login")
    response1 = s.post("https://localhost:8080/api/authentication?j_username=admin&j_password=admin", verify=False)

    for cookie in s.cookies:
        logging.info(str(cookie.name) + " : " + str(cookie.value))
    logging.info("logged in successfully " + str(response1.status_code))
    url = url1 % (params['key'])
    logging.info("inspector profile inpect api : " + url)
    response = s.put(url, verify=False)
    for cookie in s.cookies:
        logging.info(str(cookie.name) + " :: " + str(cookie.value))
    logging.info("code:-->"+ str(response.status_code))
```

Output is

```
CSRF-TOKEN : c3ea875b-3df9-4bd4-992e-2b976c150ea6 
JSESSIONID : M3WWdp0PO95ENQSJciqiEbiHZR6ge7O8HkKDkY6R 
logged in successfully 200 
profile api : localhost:8080/api/test/283 
CSRF-TOKEN :--> e5b64a66-5402-430b-8f51-d8d7549fd84e 
JSESSIONID :--> JUZBHKmqsitvlrPvWuaqfTJNH1PIJcEXPTkPYPKk 
CSRF-TOKEN :--> c3ea875b-3df9-4bd4-992e-2b976c150ea6 
JSESSIONID :--> M3WWdp0PO95ENQSJciqiEbiHZR6ge7O8HkKDkY6R
code:401
```

Looks like next api call is not using the cookies, please help me out.

Comment: What version of `requests` are you using? Earlier versions didn't have cookie persistence so have you tried to provide them manually with PUT, i.e. `s.put(url, cookies=s.cookies, verify=False)`? Finally, how can you be sure that Python is sending wrong cookies and it's not the backend rebuilding the `CSRF-TOKEN` and `JSESSIONID` - Python on its own would not generate those values so they are most definitely coming from the backend.

Answer (score 2):

Just finished debugging the same issue.

By RFC 2965:

> The term effective host name is related to host name. **If a host name
>      contains no dots, the effective host name is that name with the
>      string .local appended to it.** Otherwise the effective host name is
>      the same as the host name. Note that all effective host names
>      contain at least one dot.

Python Requests module uses http.cookiejar module to handle the cookies. It verifies the received cookies before applying them to a session.

Use the following code to get debug output:

```
import logging
import http.cookiejar

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
http.cookiejar.debug = True
```

Here is an example, when received cookie is not applied:

> ```
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar:add_cookie_header
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:80 "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 6157
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar:extract_cookies: Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 15:45:11 GMT
> Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.5.3
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 6157
> Set-Cookie: token=1234; Domain=localhost; Path=/
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar: - checking cookie token=1234
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar:   non-local domain .localhost contains no embedded dot
> ```

Requests sent to `localhost`, expect web server to set domain part of a cookie to `localhost.local`

Here is an example, when received cookie was applied correctly:

> ```
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar:add_cookie_header
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost
> DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:80 "POST /api/login HTTP/1.1" 200 6157
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar:extract_cookies: Date: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 15:52:08 GMT
> Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.5.3
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 6157
> Set-Cookie: token=1234; Domain=localhost.local; Path=/
> Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar: - checking cookie token=1234
> DEBUG:http.cookiejar: setting cookie: <Cookie token=1234 for .localhost.local/>
> ```

If you cannot fix the web server, use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your request:

```
response1 = s.post("https://127.0.0.1:8080/api/authentication?j_username=admin&j_password=admin", verify=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
from requests import Session
s = Session()
s.auth = ('username', 'password')
s.get('http://host'+'/login/page/')
response = s.get('http://host'+'/login-required-pages/')
```

Comment: I am also able to call get request after login... but not put method

Comment: @SunnyGupta What's the *Output* of your backend? if proper,  push your code to github and share the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You did not actually authenticate successfully to the website despite having `CSRF-TOKEN` and `JSESSIONID` cookies. The session data, including whether or not you're authenticated, are stored on the server side, and those cookies you're getting are only keys to such session data.

One problem I see with the way you're authenticating is that you're posting username and password as query string, which is usually only for GET requests.

Try posting with proper payload instead:

```
response1 = s.post("https://localhost:8080/api/authentication", data={'j_username': 'admin', 'j_password': 'admin'}, verify=False)
```